# how to make pyomo silent (verbosity 0) when solving a model

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm running batch of pyomo solver with different conditions and I would like to make the solver silent.

```
opt = SolverFactory('glpk') 
instance = model.create_instance(dat_file)
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True, timelimit=300)
```

In other word, when running this last line, I don't want anything printed on the stdout. Is it possible ?

A work around solution I used is to redirect stdout:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
instance = model.create_instance(dat_file)
with open("log.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    with redirect_stdout(fp):
        results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True, timelimit=300)
```

But I wonder if there is a "cleaner" solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can simply set the option `tee=False` when you solve the model to suppress all solver output.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for `verbose` or `silent` argument, I didn't think `tee` as anything to do with that. Why did they call it tee ? What does it mean ?

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I must admit though I have no idea where the term `tee` comes from :)

Comment: it's a reference to the [tee](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) command on linux

Answer (score 3):

The option `tee=False` disables only a solver log, but not the Pyomo warning messages. To disable everything you can use the following code:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('pyomo.core').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```