# How to turn off Pyomo Problem/Solver Information

Tags: python, pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I am using Pyomo to solve a problem which is running recursively in colab and there are over 1000 such linear equations.

I want to turn off all the Problem and Solver Information. I tried solutions provided here : [how to make pyomo silent (verbosity 0) when solving a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793170/how-to-make-pyomo-silent-verbosity-0-when-solving-a-model) but it isn't working for me.

`TransformationFactory('gdp.chull').apply_to(Model)`

`SolverFactory('cbc').solve(Model, tee=False).write()`

Here's a screenshot of the output which I want to turn off.
[image: Solver Information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is silent (non-verbose) by default, I believe.

You are getting the above because you are commanding it to `.write()` the result.  Just use `.solve()` without the command to write the results.

**CAUTION**:  You must check the solver status on each solve or you risk junk results.  I believe the command below works well for use with `CBC`

```
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
result = solver.solve(model)
assert(result.Solver()['Termination condition'].value == 'optimal')
```